# Argument type error on MKPlacemark

Tags: ios, swift, mkplacemark

I'm trying to write in swift a function that create a MKMapItem but I get a String error. Here is the code:

```
func mapItem() -> MKMapItem {
    let addressDictionary = [String(kABPersonAddressStreetKey): subtitle]
    let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate, addressDictionary: addressDictionary)

    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
    mapItem.name = title

    return mapItem
}
```

I got the following error when I try to create `placemark`:

> Cannot convert value of type "[String : String?]" to expected argument type "[String : AnyObject]?

Full class code :

```
class Bar: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

    // MARK: Properties
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let locationName: String
    let url: String
    let imageUrl: String
    let tags: String
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    // MARK: Initialisation
    init(id: Int, adress: String, name: String, url: String, tags: String, imageUrl: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        // Affectation des attributs
        self.id = id
        self.title = name
        self.locationName = adress
        self.url = url
        self.imageUrl = imageUrl
        self.tags = tags
        self.coordinate = coordinate
    }

    // MARK: Subtitle

    var subtitle: String {
        return locationName
    }

    // MARK: Helper

    func mapItem() -> MKMapItem {
        var addressDictionary : [String:String]?
        addressDictionary = [String(kABPersonAddressStreetKey): subtitle]

        let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate, addressDictionary: addressDictionary)

        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
        mapItem.name = title

        return mapItem
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this string :

```
  let title: String?
```

Replace this code :

```
 var subtitle: String? {
        return locationName
    }
```

You need to cast your subtitle as AnyObject as shown below:

```
let addressDict = [String(kABPersonAddressStreetKey): self.subtitle as! AnyObject]
```

and your complete code for "func mapItem() -> MKMapItem { }" will be:

```
func mapItem() -> MKMapItem {
    let addressDict = [String(kABPersonAddressStreetKey): self.subtitle as! AnyObject]
    let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: self.coordinate, addressDictionary: addressDict)

    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
    mapItem.name = self.title

    return mapItem
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your subtitle property looks like an optional String but `MKPlacemark` initializer needs a argument of type `[String : AnyObject]?` for `addressDictionary`.

What does that mean ?

The expected argument type is a dictionary where the key is a `String` and the value is of kind `AnyObject`, so it can be anything. Anything except the nil value ! But your `subtitle` property can be nil, thus you have this error.

Unwrap your value before using it :

```
func mapItem() -> MKMapItem {

    var addressDictionary : [String:String]?

    if let subtitle = subtitle {
        // The subtitle value used here is a String,
        // so addressDictionary conforms to its [String:String] type
        addressDictionary = [String(kABPersonAddressStreetKey): subtitle
    }

    let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate, addressDictionary: addressDictionary)

    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
    mapItem.name = title
    return mapItem
}
```

You can also return an optional `MKMapItem` objects if `subtitle` is nil. The choice is yours ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply !

Tho, when I tried he gave me an error on the if let subtitle = subtitle saying "Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type", so I just removed the if condition and it worked all fine.

Comment: The previous error looked like subtitle was un optionnal, but maybe it's an implicit unwrapped optional. For curiosity, what is the declaration of this variable ? Anyway i'm glad to know you resolved your issue :)

Comment: Your code works fine even with the first version of your method. If you look at the screenshot you posted first of your code ( http://i.stack.imgur.com/D589M.png ), you can see that subtitle was an optional String, so its confirm the first explanation to the issue :)